# PHP: Disallow use of $this in anonymous function

Tags: php

I am doing some kind of block renderer, where the template is rendered from the class of the Block. Since I want to disallow to use $this to protect modifying block from the view.

```
class Test
{
     function __construct()
     {
        $data["somedata"] = [1,2,3,4];
        $this->render("view.php", $data);
     }

     protected function render($file, $data = [])
     {
        $func = $this->closedRender($file, $data);
        $func();
     }

     protected function closedRender($file, $data)
     {
        return function () use ($file, $data) {
        ### Here if I use $this I gent instance of "Test" what I don't want
             extract($data);
             require $file;
          };
     }
}
```

How can I achieve this? Because people usually want's to achieve the opposite and i was unable find answers to my situation

Comment: This is why `extract()` is generally a bad idea, you don't have any control over what variables it will set.

Comment: I will not use extract, this is just quick draft. with or without extract $this is defined and it's instance of object, even in annonymous function. Only way i see is to define a global function which is not inside a class. But if there is any way then i prefer if i can have this function inside a class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this way. Define anonymous function to `static` **[`Reference`](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#functions.anonymous-functions.static)**

> **Note:** As of PHP 5.4, anonymous functions may be declared statically.

```
return static function() use ($file, $data)
{
    extract($data);
    require $file;
};
```

In static function if you try to use `print_r($this)` you will get.

> **Notice:** Undefined variable: this

Your whole code will be like this

```
class Test
{

    function __construct()
    {
        $data["somedata"] = [1, 2, 3, 4];

        $this->render("view.php", $data);
    }

    protected function render($file, $data = [])
    {
        $func = $this->closedRender($file, $data);
        $func();
    }

    protected function closedRender($file, $data)
    {
        return static function() use ($file, $data)
        {
            extract($data);
            require $file;
        };
    }

}
```